# how to pass parameters when creating a services kong api

Tags: api, microservices, kong

I'm trying to create a service in kong, which has as url which receives a pathvariable "example / {id} / example" but kong throws the following exception

curl to create the service

```
curl -i -X POST --url http://localhost:8001/services/ -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "protocol=http&host=localhost&port=8090&path=/v1/{folio}/ejemplo&name=name-services"
```

exception when creating this

```
{"strategy":"postgres","message":"schema violation (path: invalid path: '\/v1\/{folio}\/ejemplo' (characters outside of the reserved list of RFC 3986 found))","name":"schema violation","fields":{"path":"invalid path: '\/v1\/{folio}\/ejemplo' (characters outside of the reserved list of RFC 3986 found)"},"code":2}
```

please your help

Answer (score 1):

It's because your path is not encoded

From [validate_path](https://github.com/Kong/kong/blob/master/kong/db/schema/typedefs.lua#L23-L29)

```
local function validate_path(path)
  if not string.match(path, "^/[%w%.%-%_~%/%%]*$") then
    return nil,
           "invalid path: '" .. path ..
           "' (characters outside of the reserved list of RFC 3986 found)",
           "rfc3986"
  end
```

You can use `--data-urlencode` option in curl to url encode your data instead of `-d`.  Or alternatively just set path to `/v1/%7Bfolio%7D/ejemplo%26name%3Dname-services`

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it was that kong you can not set a path with a dinamic param, [https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/677#issuecomment-155883807] but in this post I found the solution

Comment: Sorry it's a bit of read, maybe you can answer your question and summarize what your solution was @MarioAaronGonzalezSanchez?

Answer (score 0):

I've found in [this](https://discuss.konghq.com/t/kong-parameter-support-in-url/3477/2) konghq discuss you can use regex in the URI.

Mapping the route as `/example/\d+/example` worked for me.